# Converting a List to Votable in Python

Tags: python, astropy

I don't think I know exactly how to use a Votable or exactly what they are but I am trying to use a database that only accepts Votables.  Is there a way to make a csv or just a list like:

```
J002716.1-014645
J003704.1-010908
J003934.8+005135
J010927.0+354305
```

Into a Votable.

I tried to use

```
from astropy.io.votable import from_table, writeto
table = from_table("mytable")
```

but get the error

```
'str' object has no attribute 'meta'
```

Answer (score 1):

astropy seems to accept many formats for the [reader](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/unified.html#built-in-table-readers-writers) including csv :

```
from astropy.table import Table

t = Table.read('inputfile.csv', format='ascii.csv')
```

You can also provide a different delimiter :

```
t = Table.read('inputfile.csv', format='ascii.csv', delimiter=';')
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me as I can not import `table` and get the error `cannot import name _core`

Comment: what astropy version are you using ?

Comment: Okay yeah that was the problem, which I had updated it but forgot to restart my editor. Thank you this worked

Comment: Do you know how to import the `to_xml`? I don't know why nothing is working

Comment: Souldn't `from astropy.io.votable.tree import to_xml` work?

Comment: do you need an import or an export ? maybe check http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/votable/index.html#reading-a-votable-file

Comment: I need an export.  Yeah I will keep trying different things I just have not had much luck with the docs I've been checking for this Votables